# List the top selling free apps of one category from Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, app-store

I want to list the top selling free/paid apps of Google Play Store for a specific category (e.g., GAME, WEATHER, SHOPPING).

Α link like : https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_paid does seem to work anymore. Any ideas?

I know about this link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free but I am interested in finding the top apps of a specific category.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to see the category with all info:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS?hl=en_US&gl=US

Or get data from:
https://old.applyzer.com/?mmenu=worldcharts

Comment: In your first link you can see that there are top free/paid subcategories. There should definitely be a way to open them as a new link (like the way my first link in the initial post does).